# Get type of generic object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I saw many similar topics, but did not find suitable for me.

I have a parent class `sealed class Item`
and a few nested:

```kotlin
data class A(val a: Int) : Item()
data class B(val b: Int) : Item()
```

There are a lists:

```kotlin
val aList = listOf<A>(...)
val bList = listOf<B>(...)
```

and some method which take a list as argument:

```kotlin
fun processList(list: List<Item>) {...}
```

How to get specific type in the `processList` method?

I know about the way with `reified` type using:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T: Item> processList(list: List<T>) {
    val type = T::class
    ...
}
```

but it cannot work with `vararg` arguments:

```kotlin
fun processList(vararg items: List<Item>) {...}
```

which is called for example `processList(aList, bList)`.

Is it possible to get type of list elements without generics?
The only idea is get type of first list element, but it is not a very nice solution.

Comment: Could you provide the example with `vararg` that doesn't work for you? I ask because `reified` is the usual way to solve this.

Comment: @broot, I have updated the question with example.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Just add `vararg` to your example with `reified` - it works as expected.

Comment: No, here is only one generic type, so the ’’’T::class’’’ will return ’’’Item’’’, which is generic type for both objects.

Comment: And how could `T` point at many different types at the same time? Or maybe you would like to get an array/list of types?

Comment: No way, so my question is about a solution without generics using.The passed lists are specific typed, so each list object should know what the type it contained I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: author of this question explained in comments that they need a way to receive `vararg` of lists and then get the parameter type of each list separately.

General answer is that this is not possible. Due to [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure) in Java/Kotlin, generic types are not known at runtime. `reified` introduced by Kotlin is an attempt to mitigate this problem at least partially, although it has its limitations as well. There are some ways to accomplish this, but they're all more like workarounds than real solutions:

**1. Do not use `vararg`, but overload the function.**

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T1: Item> processList(list1: List<T1>) {}
inline fun <reified T1: Item, T2: Item> processList(list1: List<T1>, list2: List<T2>) {}
inline fun <reified T1: Item, T2: Item, T3: Item> processList(list1: List<T1>, list2: List<T2>, list3: List<T3>) {}
...
```

Sounds really bad, but it takes 10 minutes to write such functions for up to 10 params and you do this once. Many libraries do something similar.

You can delegate each above function to a single one that accepts a list/array of `KClass`/`Class`, so your real implementation will be in a single place.

**2. Check the first item of each list.**

Very hacky and it has its limitations. You don't get the compile type, but the runtime type, which depending on your case may be not at all acceptable. It won't work well with heterogeneous collections. Also, if you need to know the type of empty lists, then this is not possible.

**3. Create your own implementation of a list which keeps its type.**

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val aList = myListOf<A>()
    val bList = myListOf<B>()
    processList(aList, bList)
}

// or:

fun main() {
    val aList = listOf<A>()
    val bList = listOf<B>()
    processList(aList.asMyList(), bList.asMyList())
}

fun processList(vararg items: MyList<Item>) {
    println(items[0].type)
    println(items[1].type)
}

inline fun <reified T : Any> myListOf(vararg items: T): MyList<T> = MyList(T::class, listOf(*items))
inline fun <reified T : Any> List<T>.asMyList(): MyList<T> = MyList(T::class, this)

class MyList<out T : Any> @PublishedApi internal constructor(
    val type: KClass<out T>,
    private val delegate: List<T>
) : List<T> by delegate
```

Of course, it has the obvious limitation that we have to use our specific list implementation.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that in general it is not possible.